Getting Token mismatch on phpmyadmin
I'm getting Token mismatch in WHM server for all of my domains.
The php.ini file
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php81"

Tried to change permission and change the path to tmp and the disk space is not full
